# Power off device from Linux

Tags: linux, power

I'm trying to find out a way to power off a device (hard drive) via `sysfs` or anything else.

The only thing I have found was to turn off the power supply to the USB device, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You can spin-down ("put to sleep" according to help page) a HDD with `hdparm -Y /dev/...`; remember to `umount` it before. Is it that you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
hdparm -Y /dev/...
```

actually worked for me.

Although I was looking for something like `echo smth > /sys/...`